# How to solve 'ERROR: invalid value for "YYYY" in source string' when trying to get previous weeks data?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get the last week of data in a pipeline script but when I do this I get the above error.

The code I am using is:

```
    where to_date(start_datetime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') >= date_trunc('week', current_date) - 7
      and to_date(start_datetime, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') < date_trunc('week', current_date)
```

I think the issue could be that the table doesn't ingest data for about 4 days after the fact (i.e if date is 12/12/22 then the most recent date is 08/12/22)

But I've tried it with getting the week that started 2 weeks ago but still get the same error.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It is likely that the issue is with the input string.  It cannot be determined that it represents a valid date and time.  Are all the values for start_datetime valid representations of dates?  Are any the empty string or just a some non-printing characters?   Can you pull a single value from the table and have this conversion work?  Can you provide sample data of what this column looks like?  The error indicates that some value in your column cannot be converted, start by looking at these values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the function to_date and your wrong input format.

If you have something like this in the start_datetime column **12/12/22**, you need to specify another format

```sql
to_date('12/12/22', 'DD/MM/YY')
```

More about formats: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html